# Adding Liebert UPS (Uninterrupted power supply) psi Range

Tags: usb, ups

I have an Liebert PowerSure PSI Line-Interactive UPS, 1000VA and using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I've used it on windows and it came up as and Notebooks battery. Is there support for these type of devices?

I've tried the Multi link software on the emerson site and found `ML_36_004_Linux_x86.bin` Which would be the software when using the 2.4.18+ Kernel. is it possible to use this file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little method to see if you can. Run `uname -a` in a terminal(Can't paste it, you must type it), and you will see a string in the form of:

```
Linux ubuntu X.X.X-XX-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 YYYYYY GNU/Linux
```

If you want to use this package, the `X.X.X-XX` part must be greater than `2.4.18-` *`[nnn]`*, where *`[nnn]`* is any number.(You are running 12.4, it should be around 3.0.0.12 or something a bit higher). Also, the `YYYYY` part of the scring (See above example) must be x86, **not x86_64** if you want to use this package. If you get x86_64, look for a package with the name `ML_36_04_Linux_X86_64`, or something like that meant for 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install Network UPS tools:

`apt-get install nut`

then configure NUT to report when your UPS sends events and act accordingly.